# How To Use Android Proxy Library

Tags: android, proxy

I'm new in android and I want to use [android proxy library](https://github.com/shouldit/android-proxy/tree/master/android-proxy-library) to get information about proxy details, and change proxy settings. I tried to get current proxy configuration and look [here](https://github.com/shouldit/android-proxy/wiki/Getting-started). There is a class which is called "ProxyConfiguration" but "APL.getCurrentProxyConfiguration(uri)" returns "Proxy" instance. And there is no class named "ProxyConfiguration" in APL.

Where I'm wrong? Can anyone put here a sample code to using APL?

Answer (score 1):

The APL.getCurrentProxyConfiguration method returns a Proxy instance which is the standard android class to store the proxy information.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Proxy.html

If you want some more information on the Wi-Fi AP and the proxy you can call the getWiFiAPConfiguration method which returns a WiFiApConfig instance (defined into the APL source code).

Comment: Why to use a whole library when this(adb shell settings put global http_proxy host:port) command can serve the same?